# Problem creating a vritualenv using virtualenv with OS X

Tags: python, virtualenv

So I'm not sure what my problem is. Trying to configure a virtualenv this is the error I get:

20:59:51 $ virtualenv test -p /usr/local/bin/python

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python
New python executable in test/bin/python
Please make sure you remove any previous custom paths from your /Users/nlang/.pydistutils.cfg file.
Overwriting test/lib/python2.6/distutils/__init__.py with new content
Installing setuptools...............done.
  Complete output from command /Users/nlang/Code/Python/venvs...ython /Users/nlang/Code/Python/venvs...stall /Library/Python/2.6/site-packa...ar.gz:
  /Users/nlang/Code/Python/venvs/test/bin/python: can't open file '/Users/nlang/Code/Python/venvs/test/bin/easy_install': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
----------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/virtualenv-1.4.9-py2.6.egg/virtualenv.py", line 1489, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/virtualenv-1.4.9-py2.6.egg/virtualenv.py", line 526, in main
    use_distribute=options.use_distribute)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/virtualenv-1.4.9-py2.6.egg/virtualenv.py", line 618, in create_environment
    install_pip(py_executable)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/virtualenv-1.4.9-py2.6.egg/virtualenv.py", line 390, in install_pip
    filter_stdout=_filter_setup)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/virtualenv-1.4.9-py2.6.egg/virtualenv.py", line 587, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/nlang/Code/Python/venvs...ython /Users/nlang/Code/Python/venvs...stall /Library/Python/2.6/site-packa...ar.gz failed with error code 2
```

I've poked around various forums and google and have been unsuccessful in getting a virtualenv created. I'm stuck :(

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what's going on from the truncated output provided but it appears you are trying to update an existing virtual environment (note the `Overwriting` message).  First, verify that the python at `/usr/local/bin/python` works correctly on its own.  Then, try creating a virtualenv in a new (non-existing) directory (something other than `test`).  If that doesn't work, edit your question to add the output from both.

Comment: Ned, Thanks for your response.

I tried to create a new virtual env, and not I'm getting all sorts of messed up.

I've somehow borked stuptools, and can't easy_install anything. 

I'm actually contemplating rebuilding my machine...easy_install is screwed up, homebrew isn't installing anything...I think it'll be a good project for me to work for tomorrow since it's a holiday. 

Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: I'm curious, did you ever find a solution? I'm getting the exact same error in the same scenario, trying to create my first virtualenv on a fairly fresh OS X install.